# can't apply sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer on only one column of pandas dataframe

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, sklearn-pandas

I have defined a custom tansformer that takes a pandas dataframe, apply a function on only one column and leaves all the remaining columns untouched. The transformer is working fine during testing, but not when I include it as part of a Pipeline.

Here's the transformer:

```
import re
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class SynopsisCleaner(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        return None
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        # nothing to learn from data.
        return self
    
    def clean_text(self, text):
        text = text.lower()
        text = re.sub(r'@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+', '', text)   
        text = re.sub(r'https?://[A-Za-z0-9./]+', '', text)   
        text = re.sub(r'www.[^ ]+', '', text)  
        text = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*www[a-zA-Z0-9]*com[a-zA-Z0-9]*', '', text)  
        text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', text)   
        text = [token for token in text.split() if len(token) > 2]
        text = ' '.join(text)
        return text
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            X[i] = self.clean_text(X[i])
        return X
```

When I test it manually like this, it is working just as expected.

```
train_synopsis = SynopsisCleaner().transform(train_data['Synopsis'])
```

But, when I include it as a part of sklearn pipeline:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# part 1: defining a column transformer that learns on only one column and transforms it
synopsis_clean_col_tran = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('synopsis_clean_col_tran', SynopsisCleaner(), ['Synopsis'])],
                                            # set remainder to passthrough to pass along all the un-specified columns untouched to the next steps
                                            remainder='passthrough')

# make a pipeline now with all the steps
pipe_1 = Pipeline(steps=[('synopsis_cleaning', synopsis_clean_col_tran)])
pipe_1.fit(train_data)
```

I get KeyError, like shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2890             try:
-> 2891                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2892             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
16 frames
<ipython-input-10-3396fa5d6092> in <module>()
      6 # make a pipeline now with all the steps
      7 pipe_1 = Pipeline(steps=[('synopsis_cleaning', synopsis_clean_col_tran)])
----> 8 pipe_1.fit(train_data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    352                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    353             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
--> 354                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    355         return self
    356 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit(self, X, y)
    482         # we use fit_transform to make sure to set sparse_output_ (for which we
    483         # need the transformed data) to have consistent output type in predict
--> 484         self.fit_transform(X, y=y)
    485         return self
    486 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    516         self._validate_remainder(X)
    517 
--> 518         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    519 
    520         if not result:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted)
    455                     message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)))
    456                 for idx, (name, trans, column, weight) in enumerate(
--> 457                         self._iter(fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True), 1))
    458         except ValueError as e:
    459             if "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in str(e):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1027             # remaining jobs.
   1028             self._iterating = False
-> 1029             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1030                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1031 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    845                 return False
    846             else:
--> 847                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    848                 return True
    849 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    763         with self._lock:
    764             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 765             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    766             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    767             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    251         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    252             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 253                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    254 
    255     def __reduce__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    251         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    252             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 253                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    254 
    255     def __reduce__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    726     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    727         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 728             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    729         else:
    730             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    569         if y is None:
    570             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 571             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    572         else:
    573             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

<ipython-input-6-004ee595d544> in transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
     20     def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
     21         for i in range(X.shape[0]):
---> 22             X[i] = self.clean_text(X[i])
     23         return X

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2891                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2892             except KeyError as err:
-> 2893                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2894 
   2895         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT 1:** without brackets and the column name specified as string, this is the error I see:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bdd42b09e2af> in <module>()
      6 # make a pipeline now with all the steps
      7 pipe_1 = Pipeline(steps=[('synopsis_cleaning', synopsis_clean_col_tran)])
----> 8 pipe_1.fit(train_data)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    352                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    353             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
--> 354                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    355         return self
    356 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit(self, X, y)
    482         # we use fit_transform to make sure to set sparse_output_ (for which we
    483         # need the transformed data) to have consistent output type in predict
--> 484         self.fit_transform(X, y=y)
    485         return self
    486 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    536 
    537         self._update_fitted_transformers(transformers)
--> 538         self._validate_output(Xs)
    539 
    540         return self._hstack(list(Xs))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _validate_output(self, result)
    400                 raise ValueError(
    401                     "The output of the '{0}' transformer should be 2D (scipy "
--> 402                     "matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame).".format(name))
    403 
    404     def _validate_features(self, n_features, feature_names):

ValueError: The output of the 'synopsis_clean_col_tran' transformer should be 2D (scipy matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame).
```

Comment: Please make sure to provide the full error traceback; that "16 frames" is hiding valuable information, specifically where the keyerror is actually occurring.

Comment: @BenReiniger, I have added the complete error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your manual test, you are passing the **Series** `train_data['Synopsis']`, but the column transformer is passing the **Frame** `train_data[['Synopsis']]`.  (So, to clarify the error: `X[i]` is trying to get the *column* named 0, which indeed does not exist.)  You should be able to fix this as easily as dropping the brackets around `'Synopsis'` in the column specification of the transformer.  [From the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

> ...A scalar string or int should be used where transformer expects X to be a 1d array-like (vector), otherwise a 2d array will be passed to the transformer. ...

That is,

```py
synopsis_clean_col_tran = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('synopsis_clean_col_tran', SynopsisCleaner(), 'Synopsis')],
    # set remainder to passthrough to pass along all the un-specified columns untouched to the next steps
    remainder='passthrough',
)
```

---

Ah, but then `ColumnTransformer` complains that the *output* of your transformer is one-dimensional; that's unfortunate.  I think the cleanest thing then is to switch your `transform` to expect both input and output as 2D.  If you'll only ever need dataframes as input (no other sklearn transformers converting to numpy arrays), then this can be relatively simple using a [`FunctionTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) instead of your custom class.

```py
def clean_text_frame(X):
    return X.applymap(clean_text)  # the function "clean_text" currently in your class.

synopsis_clean_col_tran = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('synopsis_clean_col_tran', FunctionTransformer(clean_text_frame), ['Synopsis'])],
    # set remainder to passthrough to pass along all the un-specified columns untouched to the next steps
    remainder='passthrough',
)
```

Comment: Please check my recent edit, which shows the error I got when I made the change you suggested in answer.

Comment: this fixed the error. from what I have read on stackoverflow, it would be good to adopt objects inheriting from `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin` for things like `GridSearchCV` to work properly and not have unexpected errors.

Comment: So, is there any way I can do this without `FunctionTransformer` and with class inheriting from `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin`?

Comment: Those best practices are for custom classes; `FunctionTransformer` is provided by `sklearn` and will work fine with grid search. But, sure, you can rewrite your `transform` to output a 2D array. Perhaps easiest then is to also expect 2D input, and use `applymap` on the whole thing.